# Accessibility when including SVGs directly

Tags: css, html, svg, seo, accessibility

I have been using boilerplate `.ir` for sometime to replace text with images for logos and icons.

```
.ir {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  *text-indent: 100%;
}

.ir:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 150%;
}
```

But now I would like to start using svgs for all my icons and logos and when using svgs as backgrounds or as `<img>` you can't control the innards of the svg *ie* i wouldn't be able to change a fill color.

So what I want to know is, what is the best way to include the svg while maintaining good SEO for titles and links?

Or is there any way of replacing text with an svg?

Or adding textual description like an alt tag or anything like that?

**edit**

I stated this was for SEO, but with hindsight, i'm thinking in terms of accessibility.

When including an svg image how would I describe what it is to a screen reader, in a similar way to the `<img src="#" alt="image description">` or the .ir method above?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It is about semantic markup, which is to do with SEO yes, but also about markup. However if you think that I may get a better response elsewhere please let me know.

Comment: Why would an SVG image be any different to what you already do (replacing text with an image)?

Comment: It can be done exactly the same way but you lose the ability to alter the svgs elements, plus if you include the svgs directly (<?php include('image.svg') ?>) they do not take up a request. http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: There are pros and cons to each svg implementation, I'd prefer to include them directly, but if it's at the cost text content it may not be worth it.

Comment: Some good research here: http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I'd just found this from W3C http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG-access/ (W3C, 2000) and thought I was on to something, but it seems the support for svg title and description is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a <desc> tag as the first element inside your SVG. Give it a unique id attribute and then add an aria-labelledby attribute to the SVG element itself with the value of this attribute the ID of the desc element.

This will work in all browsers and screen readers that I know-of.

If you have other elements inside your SVG (e.g. text elements), you will want to set all of them to aria-hidden="true" so that those screen readers that do read that text do not redundantly read additional information from the SVG itself.

Here is an example

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 100 50" aria-labelledby="a11yTitle" tabindex="0">
    <desc id="a11yTitle">This is an image with some example SVG text in it</desc>
    <text aria-hidden="true" writing-mode="lr"><tspan x="11.35" y="10.85" baseline-shift="0%" kerning="0" font-family="Arial_Bold_Bold" font-weight="bold" font-size="12" fill="#990099" xml:space="preserve">Cool SVG text</tspan></text>
</svg>